# Help need with transforming Java lists/collections or something

Tags: java, spring, list, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I have a list of objects returned from getJdbcTemplate().query

that look like this

```
object(test,test,test,1)
object(test,test,test,2)
object(test,test,test,3)
```

How can I transpose these into one object that looks like this

```
object(test,test,test,list<t>({1,2,3}))
```

Hopefuly you get the idea from my ropey psuedo object representation :)

Comment: Are these some sort of row-set or what?

Comment: yes the first is a rowset from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `RowMapper` can be a little painful. Perhaps, you can do something like this (by the way, this is my pseudo):-

```
List<Map> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);

MyObject obj = null;

for (Map row : rows) {
    // configure the first 3 fields upon object creation.
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = new MyObject(row.get("firstField"), row.get("secondField"), row.get("thirdField"));
    }   

    // basically add each item into the list 
    obj.addToList(row.get("fourthField"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JdbcTemplate` deals with rows, so you need a `RowMapper` to extract the values and convert them into a List of a custom type (implement a class that corresponds to this structure `object(test,test,test,1)`). Then you can work on the extracted values and assemble your new object from the list values.

**Reference:**

- [Examples of JdbcTemplate class
  usage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples)
- [`JdbcTemplate` javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)
- [`RowMapper<T>` javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a 2 dimensional array?

http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm

I'm kind of a noob at java so if I'm not correct, please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

**Extend your Object Model.**

You need to create a new object, similar to the one you are creating with the individual value argument, which instead takes a list or a collection as the final argument.  Instead of storing a single value there, your object will store a list or a collection there.  If this list or collection will be immutable once the object has been created, you should consider converting the data to an `int[]` before storing it.

Then, build whatever methods you need on this new object.  You can even write a method to return an array of the old objects, where each object has only one value in it.